# How to remove IDV Tags from AIFF file with taglib-ruby?

Tags: ruby, tags, aiff, taglib-ruby

I've been working my way through taglib's documentation but couldn't find a way to strip all Tags from an AIFF file.

The MPEG class doesn't work and I can't find one for AIFF.
Any thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that this is just not yet implemented in taglib-ruby (the wrapper for it has to be written).

I suggest creating an issue for taglib-ruby [here](https://github.com/robinst/taglib-ruby/issues).

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. Do you have further info on stripping tags from AIFF with other libs (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542658/is-there-a-way-to-remove-idv-tags-from-an-aiff-file)?