# Is there a way to remove IDV Tags from an AIFF file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-12.04, strip-tags, aiff

I'm working on a backend task system for a rails application running on an Ubuntu Server.

Before converting the uploaded AIFF files to FLAC, I need to strip all the possibly existing tags from it. How can I achieve that?

TagLib-Ruby doesn't have that covered for AIFF at this time.
Is there another gem, a command line app or something similar that my rails app could call or do I have to code that fully on my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[kid3](http://kid3.sourceforge.net/) is an application with both gui and [command line](http://kid3.sourceforge.net/kid3_en.html#kid3-cli) interfaces that allows edition of tags and supports several audio file formats, including `aiff`. You can probably script something around it in ruby and make use of it in your rails application. I am not sure if it's available in the standard ubuntu repositories, but the source code seems to include necessary metadata to build a deb (and also rpm) package, if it comes to doing it on your own.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. I'll have to work on another project for some days now - but will definitely check kid3!

Comment: I marked the answer as correct, so you get the bounty. I didn't manage to try it yet as i'm involved in more important projects at this time.